# SwiftUI: App hangs in Simulator when focusing TextField on macOS Mojave

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, swiftui, xcode11

I recently changed from coding SwiftUI on my Macbook Pro with Catalina beta to a Macbook Pro with Mojave `10.14.6 (18G103)`.

Using **iPhone Simulator**, whenever I focus a `TextField`, even the most simple app hangs. I cannot input any text and I cannot focus another textfield.

But it works (app does not hang, and textfield receives input) using an iPhone **Device** (instead of simulator) or using Catalina Beta (with simulator or device).

Has anyone else had this problem?

## Example code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var firstName = ""
    @State private var lastName = ""

    // Using an iOS 13 Simulator, focusing any of the TextFields below on macOS Mojave result in the app hanging. We cannot input anything and we cannot focus another textfield.
    // However, this works just fine on macOS Catalina Beta `19A558d` (will upgrade to Beta 11 now)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("First", text: $firstName)

            TextField("Last", text: $lastName)
            Text("Your name: '\(firstName) \(lastName)'")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I get this too. It must have started during one of the later Xcode betas. I occasionally get an error that it can’t find the right keyboard, but I haven’t been able to reproduce that message to file feedback.

Comment: It is SO annoying

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried after the latest supplemental update for Mojave 10.14.6? I just tried your sample code, and can't reproduce the issue, and the only thing I've done recently is that update earlier today.

Comment: Yes in fact I did try updating and then at first it worked, but later on failed again. Maybe I should try removing and recreating simulators?

Comment: I did that shortly after the App Store version of Xcode dropped, so that didn’t fix it. Maybe restarting fixes the issue temporarily? If I catch it again, I’ll file feedback and post the number here.

Comment: Even without SwiftUI, focusing the TextField in a UISearchBarController on an iOS simulator was hanging for me in Xcode 11 on Mojave. I don't think it's a SwiftUI thing. [People are mentioning](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/dew1xg/how_is_xcode_11_on_macos_catalina/f2zfv1i/) that this problem is resolved by updating to macOS Catalina.

Comment: every time i had to restart the simulator for work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most convenient solution, but since Catalina was released today, I tried updating to it and the issue was resolved.

Comment: It's cool that worked. The funny thing is, it happened to me while using Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

Try to quit your emulator then run this cmd in terminal:

> rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by killing the emulator and starting a fresh new one. It worked fine after that.